How to calculate the asymptotic behavior of a function after Taylor expansion
Recently I have been working on a function
$$-\frac{\log(1-a^2x^2)}{a^2}$$
when taking the limit $a\rightarrow 0$ will became $x^2$
The function also can be written as
$$-\frac{\log(1+ax)}{a^2}-\frac{\log(1-ax)}{a^2}$$
the radius of convergence for $\log(1+ax)$ is $-1<ax\leq1$, so when I do a Taylor expansion at $x=\frac{1}{a}$, the second term is not convergent, so I only expand the first term as
$$ -\frac{1}{a^2}\left ( \log{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left (-1 \right )^{n+1}a^{n}}{2^{n}\cdot n} \left ( x-\frac{1}{a} \right )^{n}\right )-\frac{\log(1-ax)}{a^2}$$
I want to know if this form of function takes the limit $a\rightarrow 0$ will go back to $x^2$.
Or if we take the finite term such as
$$ -\frac{1}{a^2}\left ( \log{2}+\frac{1}{2}a \left ( x-\frac{1}{a} \right )-\frac{1}{8}a^{2} \left ( x-\frac{1}{a} \right )^{2}\right )-\frac{\log(1-ax)}{a^2}$$
when $a\rightarrow 0$ it can not return to $x^2$, can somebody give me some analytical explanation why it can't?

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but I you rewrite the function, the limit will stay the same (for $|ax|<1$.

@garondal Since I only expanded part of the function, I don't know if the result will converge at $x=\frac{1}{a}$ as the other half can't expand, is there any theorem about this situation?
